# Importing a text file into an array with a button (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, html, button

I want a chose and open a .txt file from my pc into an array. I can do it easily with;

```
$arr = explode("\n", file_get_contents('sampledata.txt'));
```

But I want to do it with a button.

```
<input type="file" name="my_file">
```

I can chose the file with that button but I don't know how can I create an array. I'll do php calculations with the digits inside of the text file ($arr). Is that possible or am I dreaming ?

Thanks.

Comment: It uploads to a temp dir and you get details in `$_FILES`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php Also, just use `file('sampledata.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file information is in `$_FILES['my_file']`. You can do:

```
if (isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {
    $arr = file($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE);
    // ... do stuff with $arr
}
```